# Visual Studio 2015 doesn't recognize svg, rect, g, circle etc

Tags: c#, svg, visual-studio-2015

I can see a rectangle and text on the screen, so the markup seems to be correct but in the editor, there's a blue squiggly and the message that the tags aren't recognized. It seem to be the case for all SVG-related elements.

```
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <g transform="translate(0,0)">
    <rect width="5" height="5"></rect>
    <circle cx="40" cy="19" r="25"></circle>
    <text x="37" y="9.5" dy=".35em">my text</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Is there a way to fix it? I noticed that I didn't have intellisense for those elements, neither. Do I need to add a packages for that? This is what it looks like in my VS15.

[image]

Comment: Just to double check - the problem is at design time only? Everything works as expected at runtime?

Comment: Does the editor behave better if you add the required XML namespace (`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">`)? (I assume the typo in `<cicrle>` is only in your question).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm following [a blog](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/g-element.html), and there, they use the schema. I've tried both with and without it.

Comment: @ChrisF My bad. Just confusion here. The circles show too. It's only in the text editor that I see the blue squigglies (and I get no intellisense).

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/10/06/working-with-svg-files-in-visual-studio-and-visual-web-developer.aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Now I've got some time to investigate it. Thanks for the links, by the way. Turns out, setting file type to XHTML makes VS15 recognize the SVG tag. However, the page is rendered in my FF and Cr as a XML, so no page - only the markup is shown. At the moment I only have two ways, none of which is great. (a) Live with the blue squigly for SVG tag (since most of the markup is built programmatically by JS anyway). (b) Embed the graphics from an external file, be that XHTML or SVG. Do you know of another way?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I've discovered that it's not the schema of the tags thah is at fault here. It's the file extension. File.HTML makes the blue squigly come out, while File.XHTML makes it go away (but renders as a XML, not a webpage). Thoughts on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Not a big fan of answering my own questions but the response was less than intense and I finally come up with something (to a substantial extent based on the comments, courtesy of @HansPassant).*

Short version for the <strike>lazy</strike> effective coder. The problem is that the tag SVG isn't recognized as a valid element in a file with the extension HTML. I've found three ways to handle it, none of which is a real woohoo, frankly speaking.

1. Use the extension HTML as customary and render most, if not all, of the graphics using JavaScript. As it's very common to do so anyway, this is the approach I'll be using, until presented with a better option. DOwnside is that there's no intellisense support for the SVG specific tags in the markup.
2. Use the extension XHTML. That resolves the issue but the page doesn't render as a webpage at all. The browser recognizes it as a XML and renders it as such.
3. Use an external file (e.g. extension SVG) and embed it into the actual webpage. The downside of this approach is that we'll need to add yet another file (we've already got CSS, LESS, JS, partials as CSHTML etc.) to the pages flora. Also, it might prove inconvenient to manipulate the graphics from JavaScript.

Using [this resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I discovered a bunch of schemas to be added. That doesn't resolves the issue nor is necessarily required (but probably a good-to-know thing).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <!-- <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" /> -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
```

Further down in that article, there's a table on the different ways to use SVG graphics on a webpage.

There's also a [different approach](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2009/10/06/working-with-svg-files-in-visual-studio-and-visual-web-developer/) based on adding schema files to Visual Studio. It seems a bit hacky and definitely isn't something I'd like to do every time I use a new environment. Besides that, the colors of the screenshots suggest that it's a bit aged, so I've got cautious (also - a bit lazy).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like on run-time it works fine?

Visual Studio quite often (at least for me) loses Intellisense and thinks I've done things wrong. Usually a Clean & Rebuild fixes the squiggles and removes any "errors" that aren't actual errors.

Comment: Intellisense's working just fine, as it seems. And just to be on the safe side, I've rebuilt everything and also started a new, empty project. Same behavior appears and it's strictly limited to SVG. I've got some new ideas to test, though, and later today I'll visit a buddy who doesn't have the squiglies. We'll see...